# if a 2 strings BOTH present in 1 array in a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I have 2 strings "planning1" and "planning2" , I have to check if both the strings are present (whole and complete) in the same array ("active","planning","delete")

expected output: if both the strings present -> echo "true"
even if one of the string is not present in the list then -> echo "false"

I have previously tried , but it does not work as expected

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a test_array
test_array=( "active" "teardown" "planning" )
[[ " $test_array " =~ " active " ]] && [[ " $test_array " =~ " planning " ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Comment: Where are those arrays coming from? Are they some kind of text content that can be read using `grep` or `awk` or so?

Comment: Your title does not match your description.

Comment: @Dominique it is a static array, I can define it.but the two strings come from awk eg: export data_1=($(git diff-tree -p $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep state | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'))
stiring1= data_1[0] , string2=data_1[1]

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where interpolation of the entire array to a single string might be handy.
You can do that with `*` as the subscript.

## edit

Added delimiting spaces around the array and the pattern.
You could make this more precise, and modifying `$IFS` may change the bahviour - unless quoted, Bash splits input to words based on $IFS, which defaults to whitespace but you can modify it.

```
$: ray=( "active" "teardown" "planning" )
$: [[ " ${ray[*]} " =~ ' active ' && " ${ray[*]} " =~ ' passive'  ]] && echo found || echo no
no
$: [[ " ${ray[*]} " =~ ' active ' && " ${ray[*]} " =~ ' planning ' ]] && echo found || echo no
found
```

Comment: Paul Hodges , in this case [[ "${ray[*]}" =~ acti && "${ray[*]}" =~ activ ]] && echo found || echo no , it should return "no" but it returns "found"

Comment: You want whole word searches only, then. Edited to add whitespace delimiters. Should cure that.